# .htaccess file accessing issue to a specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, file-access

=> [This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLJ0S.png)

There is a file present name deploy_email.php

This is my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z](3,)\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is i want the deploy_email.php file to be access with extension and rest of the file extensions should be hidden.

If i use the above .htaccess code while inspecting, i found that the data is not get by deploy_mail.php as you can see here => [This here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azqhE.png)

Please provide some solution.

Comment: can you please add this line and check again RewriteRule ^deploy_emai.php?$ deploy-email.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST data gets lost while doing external redirection using `R` flag. You should skip all `POST` requests from redirect rule not just one file.

**Replace** all of your shown code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

# redirect only all requests except POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:php|html?)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.htm [L]
```

Clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: Yups the code worked perfect for me, the post data is now posted perfectly thanks for the whole updated code ;) :D

Comment: What if I have to do same for .html files and .htm files ? @anubhava

Comment: What if the have to add more extension like .jsp or any other then want to do ??

Comment: Don't I have to modify anything in this part ?? (?:php|html?)

Comment: Of course you need to. That's why I suggested see my changes from supporting `.php` to now supporting `html` and `htm`. You need to make that part `(?:php|jsp|html?)`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava :) your replies helped me a lot :)